# How do I upload a newly created app in the app store with my apple developer id?

Tags: ios, xcode, accounts

I need to upload my app to the app store using my apple developer id using the production certificate. Can anyone suggest me the procedure for the same.

Comment: please google it https://www.google.co.in/search?client=opera&q=step+for+uploading+app+on+itune+tutorial&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: well thanks by the way harish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you need to first create a production certificate which u have already created in this case.Then you need to goto the iTunes.connect and login using your developer account.Then you can add your app by clicking a + sign on top.This allows you to add your newly created app to be uploaded to the apple app store and will be in for review.Just follow the rest of the steps by just reading the protocol they give you at the time of your upload.u can also refer to the link that i have provided below- http://codewithchris.com/submit-your-app-to-the-app-store/

Thank you.